# Business web application: Changing column order of a grid during an application update

Tags: user-expectation, interface

So we have a grid with something like 15-20 columns and we want to change the order of the columns in a future update to better reflect the business as they don't all fit on the screen at the same time.  There seems to be a bit of an argument between changing it all in one go or doing it incrementally over a couple or more updates.

What would you advise?

Comment: The UX answer is - ask your clients. What are their concerns? How will they react to the changes? We don't know your customers. You should. If you don't you need to find out.

Comment: That's part of the issue.  I didnt want to steer the answers I got here with too much info but there is resistance to the "ask the clients" part on this particular topic.  Thx for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, you cannot find a perfect solution by making wild guesses, you absolutely have to validate your changes with your customers.

**To your specific question**

Assuming your customers support this change, I would suggest do not do incremental changes as it will force your customers to keep adjusting to the new view with each upgrade vs. just once. Gradual rolling changes are even worse if only the final state provides best UX.